# before trigger on ContentDocumentLink throwing error-Error: Null pointer exception-Attempt to reference null object-

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger tesDocUpload on ContentDocumentLink (before insert) {

     List<string> strIds = trigger.newmap.keyset() ;
     List<ContentDocumentLink> lstContDoc= [Select Id,ContentDocumentId From ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId IN: strIds ];

        for(ContentDocumentLink cd : lstContDoc){
            if(lstContDoc.size() > 3){
                cd.addError('Only 3 files can be uploaded!');
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `Trigger.newMap` in a `before insert` trigger, which is **not available** in that context. The map consists of the *Ids* of the records and that *Ids* are not generated until records have been created.

See [docs for newMap](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm):

> A map of IDs to the new versions of the sObject records.
>
> This map is only available in `before update`, `after insert`, `after update`, and `after undelete` triggers.

Comment: is there any other way to achieve this, I am trying to restrict user to not upload more than 3 files. moreever I am using chatter functionality so that I could upload 50 MB file ,, those code in javascript

Comment: Your current code does not reflect as what you are trying to achieve. Here’s my recommendation - go through some docs, trailhead to understand the data model for contents. You will necessarily need to write a validation on the record where the files are being uploaded. Once you reach to a state where you are able to write the code for same, you can then post back your specific issue so that someone can help.

Comment: Hi, My requirment is when ever I upload more than 3 files into contentDocumentLink, I must get a error messgae saying , ONLY 3 FILES CAN BE UPLOADED

Comment: As mentioned in my earlier comment, I will still recommend you to go through the data model for these objects. ContentDocumentLink is a link between the file that has been uploaded. If you need to restrict a file being uploaded, you will need to work on ContentDocument. Also if you restrict only to 3 files, then that causes an impact to your whole Org. Not sure what is your use case here but you will definitely need to go through the details and try to understand how you can approach it before implementing.